# multiplying arrays with different dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I have two questions.
How can I go about multiplying arrays with different dimensions?

```
Question 1 Example:

    A1=1,2,3,4,5,6
    A2=1,2,3
    The answer I would like to get would be
    A1*A2 =1,4,9,4,10,18
```

I was thinking of just using repmat but is this the best way?

Also

```
Question 2 Example:
A1=1,2,3,4,5,6,7  (notice the addition of another value the number 7)
A2=1,2,3
The answer I would like to get would be
A1*A2 =1,4,9,4,10,18,7 (notice the addition of another value the number 7)
```

I was thinking of for loops but the arrays are very large 500,000+ values and would take a long time to finish.

Is there a way to write some matlab/code that would work for both questions/examples?

Comment: 1,4,9...? I am not sure how you do it to get 1,4,6...

Comment: Are you doing element-wise multiplication (`A1.*A2`)? Your code says matrix multiplication (`A1*A2`)...

Comment: @Mad Physicist thanks for the catch I changed the 6 to 9 and updated the question

Comment: @kkuilla I'm not sure which one I should be using that's why I included the examples along with the answers I'm trying to get

Comment: I think you are looking for the elment-wise multiplication (`A1.*A2`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mod` to cycle through the elements of the shorter array:

```
result = A1.*A2(mod(0:numel(A1)-1,numel(A2))+1);
```

Or, if one length is an integer multiple of the other (first example), you can `reshape` the larger vector so that one dimension matches the shorter vector, and then use `bsxfun`:

```
result = bsxfun(@times, reshape(A1,numel(A2),[]), A2(:));
result = result(:).';
```

Comment: I tried your code both ways 
A1=1,2,3,4,5,6;
A2=1,2,3;
result = bsxfun(@times, reshape(A1,numel(A2),[]), A2(:));
result = result(:).'

and

A1=1,2,3,4,5,6;
A2=1,2,3;
result = A1.*A2(mod(0:numel(A1)-1,numel(A2))+1);

But the answers from my question aren't showing up am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: To define your vectors `A1` and `A2` you need to use __brackets__: `A1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]; A2=[1,2,3];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algebraic solution, if the size of `A2'*A1` is reasonable:

```
B = spdiags(A2'*A1,0:numel(A2):numel(A1))
result = B(1:numel(A1))
```

Comment: I tried your code and get a dimensions mismatch
A1=1,2,3,4,5,6;
A2=1,2,3;
B = spdiags(A1'*A2,0:numel(A1):numel(A2))
result = B(1:numel(A2))

Comment: @RickT sorry, I switched A1 and A2. corrected now. Also you need brackets for A1 and A2.